# How to search a key/value pair with a regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, dictionary, key, match

I have a JavaScript Object filled with key/value pairs and I would like to search one with a regex. Here's an example:

```
var map = {
    'my/route/one': 'Title1',
    'my/route/two': 'Title2',
    '/': 'Home'
}
```

And I would like something like this:

`var myValue = searchByKey(map, 'my/route/two');`

I did this at first:

```
searchByKey: function (map, routePattern) {
    var foundTitle,
        route;
    for (route in map) {
        if (routePattern.match(route)) {
            foundTitle = map[route];
            break;
        }
    }
    return foundTitle;
}
```

It worked, great. Then, I wanted to have something more functional, so I thought of this:

```
function searchByKey(map, routePattern) {
    var foundTitle;
    Object.keys(map).forEach(function(key) {
        if (routePattern.match(key)) {
            foundTitle = map[key];
        }
    });
    return foundTitle;
}
```

But it may match other keys like the last one `'/'`.

Do you have any idea on how achieve this in an elegant way?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `indexOf` instead of `match`?

Comment: That is because unlike the `for` loop, you can't break from a `forEach` loop, you can use `find` instead of `forEach`. Ex: `return Object.keys(map).find(function(key) {
      return routePattern.match(key);
    });`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this!

```js
function searchByKey(map, route) {
  return map[route] ? map[route] : 'not found' //return 'not found' when an invalid key is given
}

var map = {
    'my/route/one': 'Title1',
    'my/route/two': 'Title2',
    '/': 'Home'
}

var myValue = searchByKey(map, 'my/route/two')
console.log(myValue)
```

Comment: you prevent returning falsy values.

Comment: Else it will return `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the key directly?

```js
function searchByKey(object, key) {
    return object[key];
}

var map = {
    'my/route/one': 'Title1',
    'my/route/two': 'Title2',
    '/': 'Home'
}

var myValue = searchByKey(map, 'my/route/two');
console.log(myValue);
```

Another attempt with splitted keys

```js
function searchByKey(object, key) {
    var items = key.split('/');
    return Object.keys(object).filter(function(k) {
        return items.every("".match.bind(k));
    });
}

var map = {
        'my/route/one': 'Title1',
        'my/route/two': 'Title2',
        '/': 'Home'
    },
    myKeys = searchByKey(map, 'my/route/two');

console.log(myKeys);
```

Comment: Because I would have to store all my routes including the ones with parameters. For instance, a page with a title 'My Profile' can display multiple views with different routes such as 'profile/information', 'profile/password', etc. In order not to have to store all the routes, I would like to be able to use match.

Comment: ok, that maks sense. but your example is a bit misleading. mayb you add some (more) in depth examples what to search for and what you like to get.